# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable in python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am getting the error "TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable" and I have seen no solution being able to fix my problem.

The code:

```
new_high_blood_pressure = df.groupby["age"]("high_blood_pressure").reset_index()
new_high_blood_pressure
```

What I expected:

```
age | high_blood_pressure
11  | 1
22  | 0
33  | 0
44  | 1
55  | 1
```

What I got:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8088\2358215825.py in <module>
      1 #On this new data frame perform group operation as per age and create new dataframe
----> 2 new_high_blood_pressure = df.groupby["age"]("high_blood_pressure").reset_index()
      3 new_high_blood_pressure

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you want `df.groupby("age")["high_blood_pressure"].reset_index()`

Comment: I got a new error: AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Comment: What `high_blood_pressure` should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` is a method so you should use `( )` and not `[ ]` but when you select a column use `[ ]` instead of `( )`.

However you have to apply a function to the group (max, min, mean, ... or a custom function). Here an example for `max`:

```
df.groupby('age')['high_blood_pressure'].max()
```